# Am facing an error in vscode with file directories

Tags: python, pandas, path

When ever I try call a file inside the jupyter notebook to analysis for example importing a csv file.
I observed due to some reason a extra " " is being added to the path.
[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMBqz.png)
I don't know how to resolve it.
Please help.

I tried to use obsolete path but still facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

The Problem lies in the type of backslash you have given. Try changing \ with / and it should work. or simply right click on the file presented at vscode directory and at down copy the path or relative path and simply paste it here. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the \ with /

\ is a prefix for a special character.

Comment: If you look at the bottom, You can see the function received the correct path and it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens due to the use of backslash in the path, The backslash is treated as a escape character in python.

To resolve:

Use raw string 'r', `df = pd.read_csv(r'Data\sample_submission.csv')`

Comment: If you look at the bottom, You can see the function received the correct path and it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add **** to indicate file path, you can try **/(slash)** or **\ \ (double backslash)**.

***for example***

```
'Data\\sample_submission.csv'
```

or

```
'Data/sample_submission.csv'
```

*make sure your file is placed in right path first.*

Comment: If you look at the bottom, You can see the function received the correct path and it's not the problem.

Comment: python can read a file with a path like data/test.txt as relative.

Comment: Then the file really does not exits (Check the error as the path it is trying to access is correct)

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to implement a path in Python.

1. Absolute (Which I don't suggest)
2. Relative

To create a relative path you must start it with `./`, for example `./Test.txt` will point to the Test.txt file inside the project folder (Where the main file exists)

If you want access a folder in upper roots but still relative to the source you can use `..` to navigate a folder back, for example `./../` will point to the folder that the project folder is placed in.

Keep in mind, Even if you are using it in a module that is not your main Python file, Relative paths will be calculated from your main file.

In your case

```py
df = pd.read_csv('./Data/sample_submission.csv')
```

Extra tip: Use `/` or `\\` to define paths, Using `\` will break your path as it's the escape character

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp